# Current Location GPS Tracking Issue

Tags: android, google-maps

i followed this Tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

when launch the App Lat:0 and Long:0 shown on the Emulator and Mobile Device

i am using Latest Android Studio and API 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open terminal and enter:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Then enter Longitude Latitude as:

```
geo fix <longitude> <latitude>
```

Example: `geo fix 88.556(longitude) 22.567(latitude)`

Alternatively, You can open Android Device Monitor under Tools -> Android. There you can set Lat,Lng value.